# nusoap implementation for opencart

Tags: web-services, nusoap, opencart

Hope that someone is familiar with OpenCart here. I have problem with my Nusoap implementation on OpenCart. This is my implementation

1. I created a new library file called ws.php (I have the entire nusoap folder in system/library/)

> ```
> <?php
> final class Ws {
>
>       public function __construct() {
>
>           require_once('nusoap/nusoap.php');
>
>   }
>
> }
> ?>
> ```

1. I created a controller file in catalog/controller/webservice/ws.php

> ```
> <?php
> class ControllerWebserviceWs extends Controller {
>   private $error = array(); 
>
>   function __construct($registry) {
>
>       parent::__construct($registry);
>
>       $this->load->library('ws');
>       $ws = new Ws();
>
>           $this->nusoap_server = new soap_server();
>         $this->nusoap_server->configureWSDL("MemberWSDL",
> ```
>
> "urn:MemberWSDL");
>             $this->nusoap_server->register(
>                   "selectMemberInfo",
>                   array(
>                       "id" => "xsd:int",
>                   ),
>                   array("return"=>"xsd:string"),
>                   "urn:MemberWSDL",
>                   "urn:MemberWSDL#selectMemberInfo",
>                   "rpc",
>                   "encoded",
>                   "Get member's info"
>               );
>         }
>
> ```
>   function index(){
>
>       $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input"));
>
>   }
>
>   function select_member_info() {
>         function selectMemberInfo($member_id) {
>           return 'hello';
>         }
> ```
>
> $this->nusoap_server->service(file_get_contents("php://input")); 
>           }
>       }
>       ?>

1. This is my soap client residing on an application out of OpenCart

> $nusoap_client=new
>   nusoap_client("http://localhost/opencart/index.php?route=webservice/ws");
>     $id = 90001;        if($nusoap_client->fault)
>           {
>               $text = 'Error: '.$nusoap_client->fault;
>
> ```
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         if ($nusoap_client->getError())
>         {
>             $text = 'Error: '.$nusoap_client->getError();
>         }
>         else
>         {
>           $row = $nusoap_client->call(
>                 'selectMemberInfo',
>                 array($id),
>                 'urn:MemberWSDL',
>                 'urn:MemberWSDL#selectMemberInfo'
>             );
>             echo
> ```
>
> '
>
> ```
> '.htmlspecialchars($nusoap_client->response,
> ENT_QUOTES).'
> ```
>
> ';
>               }
>           }
>
> ?>

And this is what I get

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1 Date:
>   Tue, 04 Oct 2011 04:47:41 GMT Content-Type: text/xml;
>   charset=ISO-8859-1 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1 Set-Cookie:
>   PHPSESSID=fas5fisb84rcs3g94njljhrhk4; path=/ Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981
>   08:52:00 GMT Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate,
>   post-check=0, pre-check=0 Pragma: no-cache Set-Cookie: language=en;
>   expires=Thu, 03-Nov-2011 04:47:41 GMT; path=/; domain=localhost
>   Set-Cookie: currency=MYR; expires=Thu, 03-Nov-2011 04:47:41 GMT;
>   path=/; domain=localhost Server: NuSOAP Server v0.7.3 X-SOAP-Server:
>   NuSOAP/0.7.3 (1.114) Content-Length: 692
>
> xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
>   SOAP-ENV:Clientmethod 'selectMemberInfo' not defined
>   in service

Have anyone tried to implement Nusoap/SOAP in OpenCart or any idea what goes wrong in my implementation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. But i realized that if you put the `select_member_info()` outside the main class, it is working!

I will write again as soon as i get a working solution.