# Webservice in opencart

Tags: php, web-services, opencart, nusoap

I'm trying to make nusoap webservice in opencart . For that I have download nusoap library and copied it into system/library/lib,  then   I have created a controller class in checkout module like this

> ```
>     <?php
>     class ControllerCheckoutCamero extends Controller { 
>       public function index() {
>                //require_once('lib/nusoap.php');
>               $this->load->library('lib/nusoap');
>
>
>     // Create the server instance
>     $server = new soap_server();
>     // Initialize WSDL support
>     $server->configureWSDL('hellowsdl', 'urn:hellowsdl');
>
>     // Register the method to expose
>     $server->register('hello',                // method name
>         array('name' => 'xsd:string'),        // input parameters
>         array('return' => 'xsd:string'),      // output parameters
>         'urn:hellowsdl',                      // namespace
>         'urn:hellowsdl#hello',                // soapaction
>         'rpc',                                // style
>         'encoded',                            // use
>         'Says hello to the caller'            // documentation
>     );
>     // Define the method as a PHP function
>     function hello($name) {
>             return 'Hello, ' . $name;
>     }
>     // Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
>     $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
>     $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);     
>
>
>
>             }
>     }
>     ?>
> ```

then i have checked my controller by accessing localhost/myopencart/index.php?route=checkout/camero

and I get nusoap default webservice page like this [image]

But when I clicked on WSDL link on that page , I get redirected to opnecart home page

I think opencart router make this problem , but i don't know how to handle it ,I'm just started to explore opencart. I have found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7644541/nusoap-implementation-for-opencart) , but i didn't find proper answer .Can anyone  give some advice . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you code is correct.
I was trying it myself and it should work if you go to localhost/myopencart/index.php?route=checkout/camero&wsdl

nusoap code will use PHP_SELF and thus will not put the full URL for your service.

Also, when coding the client, use $client = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/myopencart/index.php?route=checkout/camero&wsdl', true);
...

Hope that's help